# Converting normal Search SQL statement with % to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following code that I'm attempting to convert to a prepared statement:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,8");
```

I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed, but this is what I have so far.

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE ? OR friend_array LIKE ? OR friend_array LIKE ? LIMIT 0,8");
$query->bind_param('sss',$username . ',%', '%,' . $username . ',%', '%,$username');
$query->execute();
etc.etc.
```

The usernames in friend_array are separated by `,` .  Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track or corrections that need to be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `FIND_IN_SET` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$username', friend_array) > 0
LIMIT 0,8;
```

You should use a statement, as you were trying to do:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, friend_array) > 0 LIMIT 0,8";
$query = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
```

But even better would be to not store CSV data in your tables.  Instead of storing a list of usernames/user IDs, store each username on a separate record.  This would *normalize* your data and make it easier to use.

Extra:

If you really needed to directly compare some `$username` against a CSV list of usernames, then just use this construct:

```
WHERE CONCAT(',', friend_array, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', '$username', ',%')
```

This would cover all possible locations in one go.  But again, use `FIND_IN_SET` with a statement, or better yet normalize your data and don't use `FIND_IN_SET` at all.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is much cleaner for this.just needed to add `$` in front of the sql statement.